# Issues with SQLServer module in powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to gather information about SQL Agent jobs from different servers. To do this, I wrote a powershell script that uses the command "Get-SQLAgentJob" and "Get-SQLAgentJobHistory".
On 18 SQL servers, this script is running fine, on the other three it just won't run, though configuration is similar.
If I open Powershell on one of these three servers and run the command "Get-SQLAgentJob" I get this message:

```
PS C:\> Get-SqlAgentJob
Get-SqlAgentJob : Failed to resolve the path 'C:\' to an object of type
'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.JobServer'. Either set your location to the proper context, or use the -Path
parameter to specify the location.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-SqlAgentJob
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (C:\:String) [Get-SqlAgentJob], SqlPowerShellContextException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ContextError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetSqlAgentJob
```

I'm kinda lost where this comes from and how I can solve this. Any ideas?

Frank

Comment: Have you read the [Get-SqlAgentJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/get-sqlagentjob) documentation? Seems like it's expecting a `JobServer` object on the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I'm an idiot. 2 servers have the SQL Agent disabled (guess I need to enable them if I want to use them), the third server is a sqlexpress (that doesn't support sql agent).

Comment: you need to update your question, not continue it in an answer part!!!